# Match an arbitrary path, or the empty string, without adding multiple Flask route decorators

Tags: python, flask, werkzeug

I want to capture all urls beginning with the prefix `/stuff`, so that the following examples match: `/users`, `/users/`, and `/users/604511/edit`.  Currently I write multiple rules to match everything.  Is there a way to write one rule to match what I want?

```
@blueprint.route('/users')
@blueprint.route('/users/')
@blueprint.route('/users/<path:path>')
def users(path=None):
    return str(path)
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's reasonable to assign multiple rules to the same endpoint.  That's the most straightforward solution.

---

If you want one rule, you can write a [custom converter](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/routing/#custom-converters) to capture either the empty string or arbitrary data beginning with a slash.

```
from flask import Flask
from werkzeug.routing import BaseConverter

class WildcardConverter(BaseConverter):
    regex = r'(|/.*?)'
    weight = 200

app = Flask(__name__)
app.url_map.converters['wildcard'] = WildcardConverter

@app.route('/users<wildcard:path>')
def users(path):
    return path

c = app.test_client()
print(c.get('/users').data)  # b''
print(c.get('/users-no-prefix').data)  # (404 NOT FOUND)
print(c.get('/users/').data)  # b'/'
print(c.get('/users/400617/edit').data)  # b'/400617/edit'
```

If you actually want to match *anything* prefixed with `/users`, for example `/users-no-slash/test`, change the rule to be more permissive: `regex = r'.*?'`.