# How to accept empty url route in flask?

Tags: python, python-3.x, http, flask

I am working with hardware machines whose firmware cannot be changed. I am supposed to make a server from them the only thing I can configure is IP and port.

For starters, I made the following server in Flask

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route("/" ,methods=['GET', 'POST', 'DELETE', 'PATCH'])
def hello_world():
    return 'Hello World!'


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0',port=5000)
```

I was getting a 308 error:

[image: error 308]

Then I used the following catch-all url approach to help my case.

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route("/", defaults={"path": ""},methods=['GET', 'POST', 'DELETE', 'PATCH'])
@app.route("/<string:path>",methods=['GET', 'POST', 'DELETE', 'PATCH'])
@app.route("/<path:path>",methods=['GET', 'POST', 'DELETE', 'PATCH'])
def hello_world():
    return 'Hello World!'


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0',port=5000)
```

But still, I am getting the same error:

[image: the error]

Comment: here is the solution I found. check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33283869/match-an-arbitrary-path-or-the-empty-string-without-adding-multiple-flask-rout) out.

Comment: Tried it ,
I got 405 which meant method not allowed,
I then added methods parameter and it was back to 308.

Comment: If you look at the second screenshot the request it not even coming at '/' it is coming at empty. normally there is a / if you send a request to that route

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does my Flask app return a response with status code 308 under test?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66612823/why-does-my-flask-app-return-a-response-with-status-code-308-under-test)

Answer (score 4):

Since I don't have 50 reputation yet, I can't comment so I'll leave this here.

You want to use the path variable for routes:

"A simple way to create a Catch-All function which serves every URL including / is to chain two route filters. One for the root path '/' and one including a path placeholder for the rest.

We can't just use one route filter including a path placeholder because each placeholder must at least catch one character."

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/', defaults={'path': ''})
@app.route('/<path:path>')
def catch_all(path):
    return 'You want path: %s' % path

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()

% curl 127.0.0.1:5000          # Matches the first rule
You want path:  
% curl 127.0.0.1:5000/foo/bar  # Matches the second rule
You want path: foo/bar
```

http://flask.pocoo.org/snippets/57/

Comment: Tried it ,
I got 405 which meant method not allowed,
I then added methods parameter and it was back to 308.

Answer (score 2):

If you insist to use empty route, Just set app.route with `strict_slashes=False`, like this:

```py
from flask import reqeust
@app.route('/', methods = ['GET','POST','DELETE', 'PATCH'], 
           strict_slashes=False)
def hello():
    return f"hello, {request.method}"
```

Because `Flask` use `werkzeug.routing.Rule`, which enable `strict_slashes` as default, visiting a branch URL without a trailing slash will redirect to the URL with a slash appended. Which cause response with 308 (Permanent Redirect).

refer: https://werkzeug.palletsprojects.com/en/1.0.x/routing/

Comment: Still applies to 2.2.x