# Why does my Flask app return a response with status code 308 under test?

Tags: flask, pytest

I'm unit testing my Flask app.
The code under test is as follows:

```py
@app.route("/my_endpoint/", methods=["GET"])
def say_hello():
    """
    Greets the user.
    """
    name = request.args.get("name")
    return f"Hello {name}"
```

The test looks like this:

```py
class TestFlaskApp:
    def test_my_endpoint(self):
        """
        Tests that my endpoint returns the result as plain text.
        :return:
        """
        client = app.test_client()
        response = client.get("/my_endpoint?name=Peter")
        assert response.status_code == status.HTTP_200_OK
        assert response.data.decode() == "Hello Peter"
```

The error is:

> Expected :200
> Actual   :308

So instead of "OK" (200) I'm getting a "Permanent Redirect" (308)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the `@app.route` ends with a slash you must also use the slash in the test:
Instead of

```py
response = client.get("/my_endpoint?name=Peter")
```

use

```py
response = client.get("/my_endpoint/?name=Peter")
```

in your unit test.

It makes sense yet took me too long time to find out.

Answer (score 3):

`Flask` use `werkzeug.routing.Rule`, which enable `strict_slashes` as default, visiting a branch URL without a trailing slash will redirect to the URL with a slash appended. Which cause response with 308 (Permanent Redirect).

So, your request path must be exactly matched with the route path.

If you want to support both routes:

- `/my_endpoint`
- `/my_endpoint/`

Just set app.route with `strict_slashes=False`, like this:

```
@app.route('/my_endpoint', methods = ['POST'], strict_slashes=False)
def view_func():
    pass
```

Comment: I understood what was happening. In fact if you use default parameters equal between two routes, you will have this problem.